# How to rename arbitary number of pandas dataframe columns from a list in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rename

I'm a beginner, you can provide feedback if you like.

I have created a pandas dataframe from a 2D list of arbitary size.  Therefore, the dataframe has arbitary number of rows and columns.  The list doesn't have headers, and so the dataframe has headers of 0, 1, 2, n.

I have a python list of the column names, but I cannot figure out how to change the header names for n columns.

I have tried df.columns = [list], which looks to work when I print the dataframe, but I feel it's actually assiging the list rather than the elements of the list.

```
    df_bs_tank_inv = pd.DataFrame(data_bs_tank_inv)
    df_bs_tank_inv.columns = [data_bs_tank_names]
```

I'd like the columns in df_bs_tank_inv, of which there will be n columns, to be replaced with the elements from data_bas_tank_names, of which there will be n elements.

Comment: Is `len(df_bs_tank_inv)` the same as `len(data_bs_tank_names)`?

Comment: If `data_bs_tank_names` is a list, just try `df_bs_tank_inv.columns = data_bs_tank_names`

Comment: When I do 'df_bs_tank_inv.columns = [data_bs_tank_names]' and then 's = list(df_bs_tank_inv), and print(s) ... I get the following:  [('Tk101',), ('TK102',), ('Tk103',), ('Tk103',)]      .... so is it doing a tupple for each header?

Comment: please show us your sample dataframe and the list so we can reproduce and come up with a solution.

Comment: It's difficult for me to provide more code.  The df are being imported from excel sheets from the following:

data_bs_tank_names = [bs_tanks_df.loc[i][0] for i in bs_tanks]

then if I print the data_bs_tank_names list, python returns: